# HTTP POST on subdomain not working

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess

Strange but is there a reason why my `$_POST` variable is not picked up by my server side script for my subdomain?

AngularJS code;

```
$scope.getLpost = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: "http://blog.example.co.uk/blog/php/resources/post-fetch.php",
        data: $.param({ 'id' : $scope.postid  }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
        return response.data.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        return [];
    });
}
```

This is my server side script;

```
<?php 

include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/blog/php/blog-db.php");
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/blog/php/blog-functions.php");

try {

    $data = array();
    $post_id = $_POST['id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE `blog_posts`.`id` = $post_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($cms_connection, $query);
    if($result) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $row['post_seo'] = seoUrl($row['post_title']);
            $data['data'][] = $row;
        }
    }

    $data['success'] = true;
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
} catch (Exception $e){
    $data = array();
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}

?>
```

As you can see I'm sending `id` from the client side.
But this is never picked up.
I've tried this in my app and also using POSTMAN but all I get is `{"success":true}`

FYI I made a subdomain by rewrites in my `.htaccess`

In POSTMAN, I have to use
`http://www.example.co.uk/path/to/script.php` instead of `http://blog.example.co.uk/path/to/script.php`

Either ways the `$_POST` is not received. If I manually put a variable in my query and run it I get the desired results.

@Steve

This is what I get from POSTMAN. As advised my `id` is not being passed;
`{"success":true,"debug":{"post":[],"sql":"SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE`blog_posts`.`id`= "}}`

This is the `.htaccess` rule

```
### Blog subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

I'm also getting this in my console:

> Redirect at origin 'http://www.example.co.uk' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://blog.example.co.uk' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: _As you can see I'm sending id_ I'm sorry I can not see where you are sending your form.

Comment: Try using `GET` instead of `POST`. How are the ID being picked up? Are you using AJAX?

Comment: You need to debug further - if you dont have xdebug or similar, then you will have to append data to the json to see whats going on, for a start, just after `$data['success'] = true;` add `$data['debug'] = array('post'=>$_POST, 'sql'=>$query);` then look at the response in `POSTMAN` and add it to your question if your are still unsure whats wrong. You should also include your htaccess rules in the question

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with `$_POST` not being picked up by the server.

```
$request = $_POST;
```

turned out empty, but

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

gave me the contents of the AJAX request. This is presumably related to the fact that AngularJS always stringifies the body of its AJAX calls behind the scenes.

Comment: Looks like this is correct - i had presumed that setting the correct header would have overridden this behavior, but apparently not

Comment: `Redirect at origin 'http://www.example.co.uk' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://blog.example.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Well, my conjecture was off then. This looks like a classic case of the `same-origin` constraint: `blog.example.co.uk` and `www.example.co.uk` are different animals, so your AJAX request is denied. At least you now know what to look for. I'm not proficient enough in Apache to help you out with this one.

Answer (score 0):

//      angular js uses payload method for posting data ,
    // while if you use url encoded header you need to convert 
    //the object posted to regular url structure. 
basically we are sending the data in reqular method and transforming the data sent into url encoded form also there is no need of param part while sending data

```
    $scope.getLpost = function () {

        return $http({
            method: 'post', 
            url: "http://blog.example.co.uk/blog/php/resources/post-fetch.php",
            data: { 'id' : $scope.postid  },  
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},  //header to accept the encoded url sent basically in string format
      transformRequest: function (obj) {  //this part of code will transform any data being sent to regular url encoded form

                            var str = [];

                            for (var p in obj)

                                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                            return str.join("&");
                        }

        }).
    then(function successCallback(response) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            return response.data.data;
        },
     function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.

       return [];
        });
    }
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: thanks for your feedback i had added some comments too for the support of this answer